# vue/composition-api ref only 1 level deep

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js, vue-composition-api

I know that with **ref** you have an object/array/primitive reactive, and if it was an object or array it is made deeply reactive.

And with **shallowRef** you can have only the variable itself reactive but is not made deeply reactive.

In my case I have an array of JSONs where I would like to make reactive the array and the first deep level, because the only actions I am doing is push/slice new items or change the array variable.

So I could use ref([]), but this will make the full JSON reactive which I don't need.
And I can not use shallowRef(), because this will work when changing the full json. But won't work with the push/slice actions.

Is there something I am missing? How can I do this approach?

```
const arr = shallowRef([]);

arr.value.push(JSON); // Not reactive
arr.value.slice(index, 1); //Not reactive
arr.value = [JSON_1, JSON_2]; //reactive
```

Comment: What is the reason for it to not be reactive? Is it performance? You can control reactivity with Object.freeze. It could probably be reactive array and not a ref then

Comment: Just use normal `ref` + [markRaw](https://v3.vuejs.org/api/basic-reactivity.html#markraw) - `arr.value.push(markRaw(JSON))`